# Drupal 7: how to hide link to secondary tab?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, hook-menu

I'm writing a Drupal 7 module. Therefore, parts of my implementation of hook_menu() look like this:

```
$items['admin/mymodule/a'] = array(
  'title' => 'A',
  'page callback' => 'mymodule_a',
  'access arguments' => array('administer mymodule'),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'weight' => 2,
);
$items['admin/mymodule/a/%id/edit'] = array(
  'title' => 'Edit',
  'page callback' => 'mymodule_edit',
  'access arguments' => array('administer mymodule'),
  'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
  'weight' => 1,
);
$items['admin/mymodule/a/%id/details'] = array(
  'title' => 'Details',
  'page callback' => 'mymodule_details',
  'access arguments' => array('administer mymodule'),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'weight' => 2,
);
```

Now what I'm trying to achieve is to hide links from the page titled 'A' to the secondary tabs, still having links among those secondary tabs, i.e. when accessing *admin/mymodule/a*, there should be no links to secondary tabs shown, while for *admin/mymodule/a/42/edit* there should be links added to both the *.../42/edit* and *.../42/details* page.
I guess this should easily be achievable, but I can't figure out how... Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to drupal myself, but I think you can use the following hook:

```
hook_menu_alter(&$items)  
// http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7
```

to alter the 'type' of the 2 last pages to MENU_CALLBACK (which will then hide the tabs for these pages)

EDIT (after reading your reply):

```
 $items['pages/render-array'] = array(
    'title' => 'Render array',
    'description' => 'Menu system example using a render array.',
    'page callback' => 'pages_render_array',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'weight' => 2,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
  $items['pages/render-array/tab1'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'title' => 'Tab 1',
  );
  $items['pages/render-array/tab2'] = array(
    'title' => 'Tab 2',
    'description' => 'Demonstrating secondary tabs.',
    'page callback' => 'pages_render_array',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
```

this is code for a page with 2 subtabs,
 I think you're able to put a condition on the 'hook_menu_alter' (= when in page 'A') to alter the other 2 pages (or something like that..?)

really sorry if this doesn't help either, just trying to brainstorm overhere :D (first week of drupal)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that won't solve the problem. I could also change the type of the last two pages to MENU_CALLBACK in first place, but accessing those pages, they should show as sub tabs.